# How am I supposed to climb the wall?

Tags: i-am-bread

I am bread and I am stuck when trying to climb the wall in the tutorial level.

I want to try one of the approaches where it is like walking. I have no troubles walking. Yet I am having a hard time doing the flip on the wall.

See me fail:

[image: I am bread and I am stuck on the climbing wall]

I am playing on the PC using a XBOX 360 gamepad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not changing the direction of the Nudge / Swing (left analog stick). You have to switch its direction midway at the highest point in order to continue climbing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a pretty difficult time with the controller, so I reverted to using mouse and keyboard. Changing the camera to be from the side a bit, and using a circular motion (like a big "C") to drag the bottom of the bread around to the top worked really well.

Another option is to swing vs flip -- have one point to anchor you ("1" for example) then you can use the mouse to pivot on that point, then use "4" (for example) to latch on above. It takes some timing, but if you get decent at it, you can move pretty fast. After just a few minutes on the wall, I started using that almost exclusively.